# How to define operations soapAction? (service stack)

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack to develop an SOAP service, and i want to customize my soap service operations soapAction (e.g.: soapAction="http://mydomain.org/operationName"), how can i achieve this ?

I've already read the documentation @ service stack's github wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack support of SOAP basically comes down to embedding the services Response DTO inside a standard SOAP message. This allows existing services to be accessible via SOAP without any consideration for SOAP itself.

Any additional support of SOAP features need to be opt-in and can be added via pull-request. The [SoapHandler.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Support/SoapHandler.cs) class is the class that prepares the SOAP response message.

Comment: So currently, the is no way to set the SoapAction (different from default) of an operation (Request DTO) ?

Comment: ok. thanhs for your answer. how i can contribute for this SOAP feauture ?

Comment: via the normal GitHub pull request.